# Why can't I get any jQuery to run in my wordpress website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Disclaimer: I'm a total jQuery novice.

**What I've tried:**
Within Magnum WP theme there are a multiple js files enqueued. I have added jQuery code to `custom.js` which is definitely linked correctly out of the box (as functions are clearly running out of it). I have also tried adding `<script>` tags within the head with the code pasted straight in at the very end (after the jQuery library is called). The theme uses jQuery so the lib is definitely linked. I've tried lots of different code snippets and I can't get any of them to work. E.g. I've been trying all day to get this one to run

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var position = $(this).scrollTop();

    jQuery('.section').each(function() {
        var target = $(this).offset().top;
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (position >= target) {
            jQuery('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a').removeClass('yes');
            jQuery('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href=#' + id + ']').addClass('yes');
        }
    });
});
```

I've also tried it with `jQuery` replaced with `$` (not sure which is semantically correct).

I can confirm that the linked html elements exist. `.yes` is referenced in my stylesheet with the rule `background: red;` which I can confirm works.

I'm all out of ideas as to why this code, or any other jquery function, will not load.

There are no relevant errors in chrome console.

Comment: something in console? errors? or just doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked console? It may be able to hint you towards a solution..

Comment: @xAqweRx No relevant errors:
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0
theme.min.js?ver=1457655677:3 carouFredSel: No element found for ".services-slider".
util.js:222 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: @M.Foldager check my reply above.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I wrapped the code that I mention in the OP and it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm not sure what that means, could you please explain? Take a look here for the live code http://hotglue.com.au/x_2013

Comment: Are you sure that the selectors return elements?

Comment: Open console and paste jQuery(selector) and check if it returns anything

Comment: @aifrim jQuery(section)
VM111892:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: section is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM111892:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM111723:145InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM111723:137InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM111723:118

Comment: Put the word section between commas man

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have both section (html element) and .section (class given to each section).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec with the `'...'` in the command it returns each of the relevant elements on the page.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec my apologies - what info would you like?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have added the code as per your link, still not working.

Comment: It's worth reiterating - there are jquery functions already running within the same file that I am adding my jquery functions.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have tried that - no luck.

Comment: you could paste in your code `console.log('step1 working');` to see if its working. then you can move it inside your code to see where is the problem. try it first in the beginning…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the code works within the console! What does this point to? That the js file isn't linked correctly?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec http://hotglue.com.au/x_2013/

Comment: There is so many jQuery errors: `TypeError: jQuery("#js-rotating").Morphext is not a function. (In 'jQuery("#js-rotating").Morphext', 'jQuery("#js-rotating").Morphext' is undefined)` and many more as an infinite loop of: `Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin https://www.youtube.com.`

Comment: You really have a problem to solve with jQuery scripts before trying this script.

Comment: I will resolve these errors and reply back.

Comment: @aifrim the html is not the issue - the jQuery runs when pasted into console.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec fixed most of the errors - just unrelated errors now. Edit: FIXED! Thank you. Please reply with the enqueuing answer and I will mark yours as correct. It may be worth writing a succinct summary for future readers: 1) check jquery selectors 2) check code in the console etc

Comment: Then you should escape your ID's when using them in selectors :) `CSS.escape` is an example :)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I can say, that you use jQuery in compatibility mode. Try this code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var position = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    jQuery('.section').each(function() {
        var target = jQuery(this).offset().top;
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        if (position >= target) {
            jQuery('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a').removeClass('yes');
            jQuery('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href*="#' + id + '"]').addClass('yes');
        }
    });
});
```

---

or this one

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(window).scroll(function() {

    var position = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.section').each(function() {
        var target = $(this).offset().top;
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (position >= target) {
            $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a').removeClass('yes');
            $('.menu-wrap > ul > li > a[href*="#' + id + '"]').addClass('yes');
        }
    });
  });

})
```

And more you are using css selectors so `a[href=#id]` is incorrect. You should pass string to value and you links are not fully matches id in selector, but only partial. So I changed it to `a[href*="#id"]`

Comment: Thank you for trying - I have tried this with no luck.

Comment: You have a problem with your custom.js. => http ://hotglue.com.au/x_2013/wp-content/themes/magnumhttp://www.hotglue.com.au/x_2013/wp-content/themes/magnum/js/custom.js?ver=4.5.2 so yuur custom js is not connected well

Comment: Fixed. Still no dice.

Comment: resolve th error custom.js?ver=4.5.2:186 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).Morphext is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112124/discussion-between-xaqwerx-and-user1395909).